Off-the-shelf solutions do you use to push last user login data to Salesforce?
We used Zapier for updating Salesforce with Okta data, such as when clients first and most recently logged in.
What are some off-the-shelf solutions to push Auth0 data to Salesforce?
We are considering to use the following, but many questions and unknowns remains:
Create Salesforce Contact object when a user first logs in.
Update Salesforce Contact object with a user's latest login, on every login.
(New feature, would be nice to have) When a user's access is revoked, mark the Salesforce Contact with this information. We may need a new Salesforce field for this.
Use Auth0 actions, or making a Lambda regularly sync data from Auth0->Salesforce.
For implementation, we need a story around getting and maintaining a Salesforce API Token. How long does the token last?
